# Run the same command on all conemu tabs

Tags: conemu

I would like to know from friends who use conemu if there is any way in Terminator to execute the same command in some or all of the open tabs of the console.

I researched but I have not found a way to do this so far.

Answer (score 0):

Open [Settings / Keys & Macro](https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsHotkeys.html) and use hotkey to start group input.

[image]